# Android and Web - need explanation

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm a french developper (nooby ^^). I want to make a streaming audio application for Android. I got the audioPlayer ready. The problem is that I don't understand how can I use my database created with MySQL and fetch necessary data from it.

I mean the very basics like an image or even a string title. My database is ready and I know how to get data from a website with the application.

Many site speak about PHP or JSON and I just keep lost more and more trying to find the answer alone.

So, can someone help me? Or give me a link to a tutorial (I already searched but maybe I choose wrong key words)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your best bet is to get acquainted with php and mysql first and then move onto the parsing of Json by Android. I'd try to Google stuff around php databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php to fetch data (in JSON) from your database.

Basically, you will call from your android device a page from your website.
This page will retrieve data from the database, convert it into a json format, then display it in the page. This page won't be in html (but still displayed in your browser), but you'll be able to parse it into objects in your device.

Some documentations about JSON :

- [For PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)
- [For Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html)

Comment: what should be the "language" of that page?  And can you tell me about parse? cause i don't really get the mean of this. thanks

Comment: Step by step, with php  :
1. Create a php page named service.php
2. In this page, you basically want to print the data from your database. So you need to get the data from it, and put it in an array (or an object).
3. When it's done, write "echo json_encode($my_value);". It'll parse your array into JSON, then print it on the page.
4. When you open the page, it has to print the value you are looking for.
5. Now, from your android application, Open this page, and use a JSON API and decode it (just type "decode json android", lots of tutorials).

Everytime you access the page, you'll get the JSON

Comment: niiiice! thanks you so much! I love you all and love that website! :D

Comment: You're welcome! If you need more information, come here again :)

Comment: hi!
 i don't know if you can still answer to me but i can't find a good tutorial to just connect to a website and receive data from it. Do you have any good site? already tryed the developer.android but don't really help me :/ and maaaaaany others showed in google

Comment: To connect to a website ? write the page address and that's it. Is your website on the internet or in local (in your machine only) ?

Comment: in local. the problem is that the app said to me that i can't connect to the database but, in my php code, the connection is written and when i show on google chrome it send me the right answers! so it work but i thinks i miss something that's different between android and chrome.
I use wamp as a server

Comment: That's because you cannot access to your server using your app.
Your device must on the same network (connect it in WIFI), and make WAMP online (http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/).
Then, when you'll have access to your website using your computer's IP address (something like 192.168.xx.xx/mywebsite/mypage.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could run a Node.js application from your server that serves the data from your sql database using JSON. For example say you have a table like so:

[image]

You can create a Restful API so that the android app can make a GET request to http://yourserverip/api/songs?numStars=4

and it will return the JSON:

```
{results: [{song: "Song A", stars: 4}, {song: "Song C", stars: 4}}
```

I wrote a [tutorial](http://antoinedahan.com/blog/BuildingRESTfulAPI/) on setting this up but there are tons of others available online.